# Telerik Grid Custom Dropdown doesn't take value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid

I am having a problem setting up my Telerik KendoUI Grid for Asp.net MVC.
Inside my grid I have linked up a custom kendo DropDownList.

The list looks like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
        new SelectListItem()
        {
          Text = "A",
          Value = "Anrufen"
        },
        new SelectListItem()
        {
          Text = "BT",
          Value = "nächster Beratungstermin"
        },
        new SelectListItem()
        {
          Text = "PT",
          Value = "Probetraining"
        },
        new SelectListItem()
        {
          Text = "V",
          Value = "Verloren"
        }
    })
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .Name("Ergebnis")
)
```

I bound it to the Telerik Grid Column like that:

```
columns.Bound(product => product.Aktion).EditorTemplateName("AktionTemplate").Title("Ergebnis");
```

Everythin works fine and the DropDown list gets displayed except that the grid doesn't take the value from the selected list element.

When I select anything from the dropdown and trying to save it, then there is no value, it is null.

**EDIT:
Controller/Action:**

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
  KundeContext kundeContext = new KundeContext();
  var result = kundeContext.Kundes.Where(x => x.KdNr == id).FirstOrDefault();

  return View(result);
}
```

**Calling Method(AngularJS):**

```
$scope.Select = function (x) {
    window.location = "http://localhost:50380/Kunde/Details/" + x;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for the action method and snippet for calling this method in your razor page

Comment: Do you mean the controller? @AmalDev

Comment: yes the action method in the controller

Comment: Updated it, does this help you? @AmalDev

Comment: How are you calling this Details method from client side, on a button click ? If yes, then can you post that too ?

Comment: Updated it again. Yes there is a button and then I am calling it via AngularJS where x represents an integer, the Id of the user. @AmalDev

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121861/discussion-between-amal-dev-and-anokrize).

Comment: Try changing the `Name` property of your dropdownlist to 'Aktion' instead of 'Ergebnis'. From my experience the dropdown needs to have the same name as the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/editor-templates) on Editor Templates.

> The name of the widget should be the same as the name of the property.

Try changing the `Name` property of your dropdownlist to 'Aktion' instead of 'Ergebnis'.